# Как запретить анимацию при загрузке изображений?

Tags: анимация, php, изображения

Как сделать, чтоб при загрузке на сервер картинки, если она анимированая, эту анимацию убрать? Даже если пользователь тупо переименует расширение картинки.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow:[How to convert animated GIF to static in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380214/how-to-convert-animated-gif-to-static-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

Меняйте расширение. Если (расширение_файла == .gif) {файл = имя_файла.jpg}

Comment: А если я поменял у анимации gif на jpg то условие не сработает
да и не желательно менять расширение у загружаемых файлов

Comment: 1. Какое условие не срабатывает?2. Почему не желательно менять расширение? Кстати, по другому анимированный гифчик вы не заставите быть статическим.3. Любите усложнять? Тогда создавайте копию изображения с первым кадром. Подробнее - [найдёте тут (imagecreatefromgif)](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreatefromgif.php#82912). Только и в этом случаем расширение придётся менять. Или же делать двойную работу: из **gif** в **png**, из **png** в **gif**